# sort merge code in java needs some clarifications

Tags: java

Can you explain some lines below please ( I put ? in front of each line that needed to be explained). Thanks in advance !
I know that :
Merge-sort on an input sequence S with n elements consists of three steps:
Divide: partition S into two sequences S1 and S2 of about n/2 elements each
Recur: recursively sort S1 and S2
Conquer: merge S1 and S2 into a unique sorted sequence

But when I read the code I lost my way, can you just guid me please.

```
public class MergeSort {
        public static int[] mergeSort(int [] list) {
            if (list.length <= 1) {
                return list;
            }

            // Split the array in half
            int[] first = new int[list.length / 2];  // ok
            int[] second = new int[list.length - first.length]; // ?
            System.arraycopy(list, 0, first, 0, first.length);  // ?
            System.arraycopy(list, first.length, second, 0, second.length); // not sure ?

            // Sort each half
            mergeSort(first); // ok
            mergeSort(second); // ok

            // Merge the halves together, overwriting the original array
            merge(first, second, list); // ok
            return list; // ok
        }

        private static void merge(int[] first, int[] second, int [] result) { // explain in general ?
            // Merge both halves into the result array
            // Next element to consider in the first array
            int iFirst = 0;
            // Next element to consider in the second array
            int iSecond = 0;

            // Next open position in the result
            int j = 0;
            // As long as neither iFirst nor iSecond is past the end, move the
            // smaller element into the result.
            while (iFirst < first.length && iSecond < second.length) { // ??!!
                if (first[iFirst] < second[iSecond]) {
                    result[j] = first[iFirst];
                    iFirst++;
                    } else {
                    result[j] = second[iSecond];
                    iSecond++;
                }
                j++;
            }
            // copy what's left
            System.arraycopy(first, iFirst, result, j, first.length - iFirst);
            System.arraycopy(second, iSecond, result, j, second.length - iSecond);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
        {
            String list="";
            int i=0,n=0;

            MergeSort s= new MergeSort();
            ArrayList<Integer> arrlist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the list of elements,one element per line");
            System.out.println(" write 'STOP' when list is completed ");
            BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while(!(list=bf.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
                int intelement=Integer.parseInt(list);
                arrlist.add(intelement);

            }

            int elementlist[]  = new int[arrlist.size()];
            Iterator<Integer> iter = arrlist.iterator();
            for (int j=0;iter.hasNext();j++) {
                elementlist[j] = iter.next();
            }

            elementlist=mergeSort(elementlist); // ?
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Values after Merge Sort : ");
            for (int j=0;j<elementlist.length;j++) {
                System.out.println(elementlist[j]+" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `int[] first = new int[list.length / 2];` and  `int[] second = new int[list.length - first.length];` method is dividing the list into 2 arrays, lets say your list has a length of 5 first will have 2 as its size and 3 for second. In

```
System.arraycopy(list, 0, first, 0, first.length); 
System.arraycopy(list, first.length, second, 0, second.length);
```

your populating both first and second arrays from your list array( copy `list[0],list[1]` to first array and `list[2],list[3],list[4]` to second array).

In  `private static void merge(int[] first, int[] second, int [] result)` you are merging `first` and  `second` arrays and overwriting the `result` array 
in the `while` loop you take the first element of first and second arrays and comparing them and move the smallest to `result[0]` then increment the pointer to arrays accordingly by using `if and else` statements and now you have the smallest element in both `first` and `second` arrays placed in `result[0]` .

You increment  `j` ,it means in this iteration you will put the second smallest element in `result[1]` and so on.

In `elementlist=mergeSort(elementlist);` you are sorting `elementlist` by invoking your `mergeSort(int [] list);` method.

Comment: Many thanks, then what is happening in last part, public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception

Comment: you instantiate a MergSort and ArrayList objects , and after printing messages into console and instantiating BufferedReader  " bf "  object , you use the bf object inside the while loop to capture the user inputs and save them into an array named arrlist. The while loop will be terminated when a user, writs stop ,then in next for loop you copy arrlist to elementlist and so on. throws Exception  is included beacuse you are using InputStreamReader object that may throw exception

Comment: Thank you so much.